# Styles in Orchid laravel

Tags: laravel, orchid

I created a Laravel project as per the instructions https://orchid.software/en/docs/quickstart/

As a result, it turned out that the administrative panel Orchid styles did not work. How can I fix this?

Current file path's:

> /vendor/orchid/css/orchid.css?id=3578927bc9308e7a38b3c81d38a8cdad
> /vendor/orchid/js/manifest.js?id=fa18bd350409678078668239241217f5
> /vendor/orchid/js/vendor.js?id=627078ee16848736db22766555ad6401
> /vendor/orchid/js/orchid.js?id=b39b4e447cf753dd191ab747020e2d32

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. And the solution is very simple actually. Just add

```
'mix_url' => env('MIX_URL', null),
```

to config/app.php

But before that, set MIX_URL value on .env

And then run

- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan orchid:publish

hope it helps.

For more explanation, check this: https://github.com/orchidsoftware/platform/issues/2237

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing [this](https://orchid.software/en/docs/installation/#keeping-assets-updated) to keep assets updated:

On `composer.json` put:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@php artisan orchid:publish --ansi"
  ]
}
```

then check if everything is ok by:

```
php artisan about
```

Comment: I added the following code structure to this file:
     "post-update2-cmd": [
       "@php artisan orchid:publish --ansi"
   ]

Then I ran the command artisan orchid:publish --ansi in the console. As a result, a \vendor\ folder appeared in the \public\ folder, containing styles and scripts, however, the admin panel is still displayed with the styles missing.

Comment: can you do this 2 commands: `php artisan orchid:publish` and 
`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: yes, I ran all the commands, but it didn't help

Comment: I created this project on local web server (Open Server). Current path in file: /vendor/orchid/css/orchid.css?id=3578927bc9308e7a38b3c81d38a8cdad. Maybe this somehow affects the error?

Comment: I run commands and file was copy. I still haven't solved the problem with styles. Where are styles connected in blade (view of framework)? Help me, please anyone.

Comment: @IntegralAL + help  [here](https://github.com/orgs/orchidsoftware/discussions/categories/q-a?discussions_q=is%3Aopen+category%3AQ%26A), Sorry